# Spark Streaming Dataset Cassandra Connection UnsupportedOperationChecker

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am attempting to write my Streaming Dataset into Cassandra.

I have the following streaming dataset of class;

```
case class UserSession(var id: Int,
                       var visited: List[String]
                      )
```

I also have the following keyspace/table in Cassandra. (Blog=KeySpace, session=Table

```
CREATE KEYSPACE blog WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',    'replication_factor' : 1 };


CREATE TABLE blog.session(id int PRIMARY KEY, visited list<text>);
```

I chose `list<text>` for visited because my visited is type `List<String>`

My foreach writer is as the following

```
class SessionCassandraForeachWriter extends ForeachWriter[UserSession] {

/*
  - on every batch, on every partition `partitionId`
    - on every "epoch" = chunk of data
      - call the open method; if false, skip this chunk
      - for each entry in this chunk, call the process method
      - call the close method either at the end of the chunk or with an error if it was thrown
 */

val keyspace = "blog"
val table = "session"
val connector = CassandraConnector(sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf)

override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = {
  println("Open connection")
  true
}

override def process(sess: UserSession): Unit = {
  connector.withSessionDo { session =>
    session.execute(
      s"""
         |insert into $keyspace.$table("id")
         |values (${sess.id},${sess.visited})
       """.stripMargin)
  }
}

override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = println("Closing connection")

 }
```

It may help to look at my process function since this may be throwing an error. My main is the following.

finishedUserSessionsStream: DataSet[UserSession]

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
/// make finishedUserSessionStreams.....

finishedUserSessionsStream.writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
      .foreach(new SessionCassandraForeachWriter)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()

}
```

This gives me the following error

at `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:431)`

Comment: what version of Spark Cassandra Connector is used? And Spark version

Comment: spark cassandra connector is "3.0.0-alpha2" and I'm using spark version
3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark 3.0 & Spark Cassandra Connector 3.0.0 you shouldn't use `foreach` - it was a workaround for SCC < 2.5.0 that didn't have native support for writing streaming datasets.  [Starting with SCC 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all), you can just directly write data to Cassandra, like this (here is [full example](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/scc-2.5/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingKafkaDSE.scala)):

```scala
     val query = streamingCountsDF.writeStream
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
      .option("keyspace", "ks")
      .option("table", "table")
      .start()
```

You also need to switch to use of SCC 3.0.0-beta that contains a lot of fixes.

Comment: OutputMode.Update is not supported from the error messages. I changed it to Append. Then it goes back to the original problem with org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.throwError

Comment: do you call `.cache` on the streaming dataset? If yes, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20927

Comment: did not cache it. I changed it back to update and the error is this

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: session does not support Update mode.

session is a table within cassandra(the one i have locally).  Do you think I should chang e how I create the session table?

Comment: it should work with `append` mode, but may depend on the transformations that you're doing prior to writing

Comment: Ah to give some further context. I am doing MapGroupWithState beforehand. But it should ends up in a Dataset[UserSession] object. It works perfectly when I write it to the console

Comment: I changed my version back to 2.5.1 and then I went back to the foreach method.

it seems that's cassandra can't accept a list[String]. so I had to convert it to String in my process method.

for e.g.
override def process(sess: UserSession): Unit = {
      connector.withSessionDo { session =>
        session.execute(
          s"""
             |insert into $keyspace.$table("id","visited")
             |values (${sess.id}, '${sess.visited.toString()}')
           """.stripMargin)
      }
    }

Comment: try at least `foreachBatch` - it should be easier: https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingForEachBatch.scala - because your code isn't really correctly formatting data in `insert`